# How do I randomly output string to multiple labels from array without repeats

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basketball playoff simulator. I have an array for east conference teams and west conference teams. I want to randomly output the team names to the first 4 labels on each side with no repeats. How do I generate random unique seeds for each team.

```java
private void btnSeedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        
        lblSeriesWins.setText(String.valueOf("0"));
        
        String TeamName = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        
        String Raptors = "Raptors";
        String Bucks = "Bucks";
        String Phila = "76ers";
        String Celtics = "Celtics";
        
        String [ ] eastTeams = {"Raptors","Bucks", "76ers", "Celtics"};
        Random random1 = new Random();
        int PickEast = random1.nextInt(eastTeams.length);
        
        lblFirstTeamEast.setText(String.valueOf(eastTeams[PickEast]));
        lblSecondTeamEast.setText(String.valueOf(eastTeams[PickEast])); 
        lblThirdTeamEast.setText(String.valueOf(eastTeams[PickEast]));
        lblFourthTeamEast.setText(String.valueOf(eastTeams[PickEast]));
        
        String[ ] westTeams = {"Lakers", "Warriors", "Suns", "Grizzlies"};
        Random random2 = new Random();
        int PickWest = random2.nextInt(westTeams.length);
        
        lblFirstTeamWest.setText(String.valueOf(westTeams[PickWest]));
        lblSecondTeamWest.setText(String.valueOf(westTeams[PickWest]));
        lblThirdTeamWest.setText(String.valueOf(westTeams[PickWest]));
        lblFourthTeamWest.setText(String.valueOf(westTeams[PickWest]));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could put the names in a list and then shuffle the list, giving you a random order with no duplicates:

```java
List<String> eastTeams = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Raptors", "Bucks", "76ers", "Celtics"));
Collections.shuffle(eastTeams);

lblFirstTeamEast.setText(eastTeams.get(0));
lblSecondTeamEast.setText(eastTeams.get(1)); 
lblThirdTeamEast.setText(eastTeams.get(2));
lblFourthTeamEast.setText(eastTeams.get(3));
```